# Can no longer access the list of API descriptors after installing Glimpse

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, glimpse

We would like to use Glimpse in our ASP.net MVC project but are running into a problem when accessing the list of Web API descriptors.

We have installed Glimpse.Mvc4 1.2.2 using the Nuget Package Manager.

The following snippet gets all API descriptors and it works fine before we install Glimpse. After installing we do only get an empty list.

```
IEnumerable<ApiDescription> apiDescriptors = System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration
           .Configuration
           .Services
           .GetApiExplorer()
           .ApiDescriptions
```

Does anyone know why this call does not work when Glimpse is installed?

Comment: This sounds like it could be a bug. Glimpse doesn't do anything specific that could interfere with WebAPI, but there may be something strange happening in that call. Please feel free to [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse/issues) so we can track this down and fix it.

Comment: This just happened to me as well and I reproduced it on a clean project.  When I uninstalled Glimpse via NuGet, the APIs came back.  The issue is specifically with the ApiExplorer which looks at your controllers and routes to build metadata for your APIs.  Was there an issue opened up on the Glimpse project (I didn't see it)?

Comment: I did open an issue on the Glimpse project a few weeks ago: https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/365
I have not yet got any response though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Glimpse ASP.NET module wraps all routes in its own objects. So API Explorer ignores them (thinks that they are not Web API routes).

To work around this issue, you must initialize a fresh copy of `System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration` instead of using `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration`.

```
// need to create a custom configuration instance because the default one can be 
// processed by Glimpse and be thus full of wrapped routesthat the ApiExplorer 
// does not recognize.
var config = new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration();
WebApiConfig.Register(config);

// these line is useful if you use WebAPI Help page package
HelpPageConfig.Register(config);
Controllers.HelpController.Configuration = config;

// otherwise just get the `IApiExplorer` interface from the fresh configuration:
var apis = config.Services.GetApiExplorer().ApiDescriptions;
```